# Mostrar Datos usando keyup (No funciona)

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Necesito que al escribir en un input de tipo text, si lo que escribí corresponde a un valor de la base de datos, el resultado, que en este caso seria el nombre de un estudiante, se muestre en otro input de tipo text. Los datos los estoy ingresando en un modal, pero al escribir en el input, no me muestra el resultado(dentro del mismo modal). Les dejo el código por si saben que le falta o que debo corregir, se los agradecería. Me arroja este Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity:
>   Notice
>
> Message:  Array to string conversion
>
> Filename:
>   models/mCalendar.php
>
> Line Number:
>   59
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\models\mCalendar.php
>             Line:
>   59
>           Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\cCalendar.php            Line: 52
>           Function:
>   buscar_estudiante                                                                          File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\index.php            Line: 315
>          Function: require_once                      Array

La linea 59 es  echo $estudiante;

Model(mCalendar)

```
 public function buscar_estudiante($rut_estu){


  $this->db->select('CONCAT(pnombre, " ",apellido_pa," ", apellido_ma) As estudiante');
  $this->db->from('estudiantes');
  $this->db->where('rut_estu',$rut_estu);
  $estudiante = $this->db->get()->result();

   echo $estudiante;

 }
```

Controlador(cCalendar)

```
 public function buscar_estudiante(){


    $rut_estu=  $this->input->post('rut_estu');
    $estudiante = $this->mCalendar->buscar_estudiante($rut_estu);

}
```

javascript dentro de la Vista

```
 $("#rut_estu").keyup(function(){

    var parametros = {

            "rut_estu" :$("#rut_estu").val(),

           }

      $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   '<?php echo base_url();?>cCalendar/buscar_estudiante',
            type:  'post',
            beforeSend: function () {

                $("#nombre_estu").val();

            },
            success:  function (response) {
                $("#nombre_estu").val(response); 

            }
      });


   });
```

Comment: Donde dice `("#rut_estu").keyup` falta un `$` al comienzo ¿en el código lo tienes así o fue un accidente al copiar y pegar aquí?

Comment: #rut_estu es el id del input donde estoy escribiendo, no debe llevar un $

Comment: Me refiero a que debería ser `$("#rut_estu")`, de lo contrario estás intentando usar la función `keyup` de un string, en lugar de un objeto jQuery.

Comment: Oh, no tenia idea, le agregue eso, y le puse un alert para ver que arrojaba, pero no me mostraba nada solo decía [objet]

Comment: Tienes en el where $this->dd y es $this->db podria ser eso?

Comment: Editado, gracias

Comment: Pero no funciona :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que estás utilizando jQuery (por la parte de `$.ajax`) y CodeIngniter (por la parte de `$this->db->select`). Si ambas son ciertas, entonces debes cambiar tu código por:

```
$("#rut_estu").keyup(function(){
```

Pues te faltaba el símbolo `$`

En cuanto al PHP, CodeIgniter te devuelve el objeto completo al ejecutar `$this->db->get()->result()`, así que deberías cambiar el código por:

```
echo $estudiante[0]->estudiante;
```

Pues lo que quieres es el valor de la columna `estudiante` (de acuerdo a tu consulta)

Comment: Si amigo, estoy usando JQuery(además de codeigniter)  también, le agregue el $que le faltaba y el echo $estudiante->estudiante; pero sigue sin mostrarme nada :C no se que más podría estar fallando; los datos los escribo en un modal, no se si eso tiene algo que ver

Comment: Que raro, ya con eso debería enviar el valor de esa columna, y el resto de tu código parece bien. Quitaste el otro `echo`?

Comment: Debía de agregar esto en el modal, el row, eso me dijeron, y ahora muestra el valor. Código:   $estudiante = $this->db->get()->row();

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, no recordaba que `result()` devuelve un arreglo

Comment: Gracias igualmente por tu ayuda :D

Comment: No hay de queso, no más de papa :D

Answer (score 0):

rut_estu que pasas por el parametro es el name, no el ID, para buscarlos por rut_estu

```
 ("input[name='rut_estu']").keyup(function(){

var parametros = {

        "rut_estu" :$("input[name='rut_estu']").val(),

       }

  $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:   '<?php echo base_url();?>cCalendar/buscar_estudiante',
        type:  'post',
        beforeSend: function () {

            $("input[name='rut_estu']").val();

        },
        success:  function (response) {
            $("input[name='nombre_estu']").val(response); 

        }
  });
```

});

para comprobarlo usa las herramientas de desarrollador

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero sigue sin funcionar :C no se que podría ser

Comment: no entiendo bien tus input de nombre_estu y rut_estu, el primero nunca lo veo declarado, trata de con la información que te dí, armar bien tus input y revisar si no hay errores en la consola. También borra cache ya que luego es el problema en javascript

Answer (score 0):

nombre_estu es el nombre/id de un input, y está en el javascript, esto lo e hecho antes con php solo, sin codeigniter y funciona bien, aunque usa un while, no se como seria en este caso....este es el código con php solo para un sistema anterior que hice.

```
  function buscar_cliente3(){

        $rut_usu=$this->rut_usu;
        $sql="SELECT usuarios.rut_usu, usuarios.apellido_pa
            FROM usuarios
            INNER JOIN perfiles ON usuarios.id_per=perfiles.id_per
            INNER JOIN region ON usuarios.id_reg=region.id_reg
            INNER JOIN provincia ON usuarios.id_pro=provincia.id_pro
            INNER JOIN comuna ON usuarios.id_com=comuna.id_com
            WHERE usuarios.rut_usu = '$rut_usu'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $sql);
            $pnombre="";
            $snombre="";
            $apellido_pa="";
            $apellido_ma="";
            while ( $datos=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado) ){
                $apellido_pa =$datos["apellido_pa"];

            }

                        echo $apellido_pa;

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, gracias a la comunidad por su ayuda, el model debe quedar de esta forma

```
public function buscar_estudiante($rut_estu){


  $this->db->select('CONCAT(pnombre, " ",apellido_pa," ", apellido_ma) As estudiante');
  $this->db->from('estudiantes');
  $this->db->where('rut_estu ',$rut_estu);
  $estudiante = $this->db->get()->row();



   //return $estudiante;

   echo $estudiante->estudiante;

}
```